# elseif not working with header location

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to get **userclass** to equal **home** when the user is on either **usercp.php** or **profile.php**, but I can't seem to get the following elseif to work:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/usercp.php') {
   $userclass = "home";
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/profile.php') {
   $userclass = "home";
} else {
   $userclass = "norm";
}
```

Comment: Did you wrote: `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` just once and looked at the output?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try: `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to see the value of the variable.

Don´t forget that REQUEST_URI returns the path relative to the server root directory. So, if You have your php file inside a directory called "test", the string returned by REQUEST_URI will be "/test/thefile.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ?

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'usercp.php')) {
   $userclass = "home";
} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'profile.php')) {
   $userclass = "home";
}
```

Or echo your $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and make comparison like  Rizier123 comment.